# Jackrabbit error on starting as JBoss module

Tags: jboss, jackrabbit, jcr

I've decided to use jackrabbit and JCR 2.0 for creating a simple web DMS system. I am using JBoss and then added JCR as module and successfyllu deployed jackrabbit and my own web app. I've tested the app and it seems to work ok. The problem is when starting the server I get this exception and eclipse throws me in debug mode. Everything seems to be working ok, but what causes this exception and more importantly how do I get rid of it?

Edit: Searched quite a while but coundn't find anything on the Internet.

```
13:24:25,419 ERROR [stderr] (JCA PoolFiller) Exception in thread "JCA PoolFiller" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Retrieving meta data not supported.

    13:24:25,420 ERROR [stderr] (JCA PoolFiller)    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.AnonymousConnection.getMetaData(AnonymousConnection.java:125)

    13:24:25,421 ERROR [stderr] (JCA PoolFiller)    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.createConnectionListener(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:540)

    13:24:25,422 ERROR [stderr] (JCA PoolFiller)    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:767)

    13:24:25,422 ERROR [stderr] (JCA PoolFiller)    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.fillToMin(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:706)

    13:24:25,423 ERROR [stderr] (JCA PoolFiller)    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:97)

    13:24:25,423 ERROR [stderr] (JCA PoolFiller)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Found solution? :)

Comment: As far as I remember (this was some years ago :D ) couldn't find the problem and since it did not cause problems I have decided to leave it this way.